# Javascript Image Link

Tags: javascript, image

I would like to have an image appear when a button is clicked. I think that I have gotten everything in the code right, but I need help with the image link.

I would like to take the image from a website. What is the code that I add to this code to make it do this?

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function pic1()
    {
        document.getElementById("img").src =";
    }
```

```
<img src = "" id = "img"/> <input type="button" value="Click for image!" onclick="pic1()"/>
```

Comment: "src" is an attribute so you set it with element.setAttribute() see here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute

Comment: You can just enter the URL in your existing code. Ex: `document.getElementById("img").src = 'https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png';`. http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/tof3yy8b/

Comment: @Dinesh Is there something wrong with setting it by using `.src`? I've never had any trouble doing it that way.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek I have tended to use the function call but I suppose there is always something new to learn :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
function pic1()
{
    //set this to the url of whatever image you want to appear
    var imageUrl = "https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png";
    document.getElementById("img").setAttribute("src",imageUrl);
}
```

```html
<img src="" id="img"/>
<input type="button" value="Click for image!" onclick="pic1()"/>
```